# update input in form using enzyme

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, react-hooks

I'm using React hooks and enzyme & jest, trying to update the form input value using enzyme in my tests however I get no update

the tests run fine on the input but when I try to update I get no value

```
  it("should display an item", () => {
    const input = wrapper.find('[name="title"]')
    input.simulate("change", { target: { value: "Buy Bread" } })
    expect(input).toHaveValue("Buy Bread")
    //more code later
  })
```

I eventually want to submit the form to see results from the state change.

Am I missing something here? I've tried various suggestions to no avail

toHaveValue (jest-enzyme) shows the input with no value change

Comment: What you are doing is correct, aren't you getting any error? However, could be that your React component is somehow restricting the input to update?

Comment: are you using `mount` or `shallow`?

Comment: brian-lives-outdoors I'm using mount